# IOCP AcceptEx not creating completion upon connect

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, iocp

I am currently trying some new libraries (IOCP) for socket programming. And I've stumbled upon the [AcceptEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functionality to enable async connections.

As the documentation says:

> The AcceptEx function uses overlapped I/O, unlike the accept function. If your application uses AcceptEx, it can service a large number of clients with a relatively small number of threads. As with all overlapped Windows functions, either Windows events or completion ports can be used as a completion notification mechanism.

But I am not receving any completion when a client connects. I do however get a completion when the client sends data..

This is my code:

```
DWORD dwBytes;
GUID GuidAcceptEx = WSAID_ACCEPTEX;
int iResult = WSAIoctl(m_hSocket, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,
    &GuidAcceptEx, sizeof (GuidAcceptEx), 
    &m_lpfnAcceptEx, sizeof (m_lpfnAcceptEx), 
    &dwBytes, NULL, NULL);

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    CloseSocket();
}
```

And then:

```
WSAOVERLAPPED olOverlap;
memset(&olOverlap, 0, sizeof (olOverlap));
char lpOutputBuf[1024];
int outBufLen = 1024;
DWORD dwBytes;

BOOL bRet = m_lpfnAcceptEx( m_hSocket, hSocket, lpOutputBuf,
             outBufLen - ((sizeof (sockaddr_in) + 16) * 2),
             sizeof (sockaddr_in) + 16, sizeof (sockaddr_in) + 16, 
             &dwBytes, &olOverlap);
if ( bRet == FALSE )
{
    DWORD dwRet = WSAGetLastError();
    if( dwRet != WSA_IO_PENDING )
    {
        return dwRet;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion of what to do to receive completions?

EDIT:
I bind the hSocket to the completionport after m_lpfnAcceptEx()

Comment: Non zero dwReceiveDataLength, so MSDN 'If dwReceiveDataLength is zero, accepting the connection will not result in a receive operation. Instead, AcceptEx completes as soon as a connection arrives, without waiting for any data.' does NOT apply.  Also, this code does not look very C++ ish.

Comment: outBufLen - ((sizeof (sockaddr_in) + 16) * 2) is in my case 960 so thats not the issue..

Comment: it is not not the issue:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly the `WSAOVERLAPPED` and data buffer that you're declaring on the stack above your call to `AcceptEx()` will not be in existence when a completion occurs (unless you are calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` in the same function, which would be a trifle odd). You need to dynamically allocate them or pool them.

Secondly you state that you associate the socket to the completion port after you call `AcceptEx()`. That's wrong. You need to do these things before you call `AcceptEx()`.

1. Create a socket with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` set.
2. Bind it to the address you want to listen on.
3. Call listen on it with your desired backlog.
4. Load `AcceptEx()` dynamically using the listening socket and a call to `WSAIoctl` (not strictly necessary and the code you show should work but this way you can be sure you get your listening socket from the same underlying winsock provider and that it supports AcceptEx().
5. Load `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` in the same way as you load `AcceptEx()` - you'll need it once the accept completes.
6. Associate the listening socket to your IOCP.

Now you can post a number of `AcceptEx()` calls using the listening socket and new 'accept' socket which you create like this:

1. Create a socket with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` set.
2. Associate the socket to your IOCP.

As stated above you need to ensure that the buffer and the OVERLAPPED are unique per call and last until the completion occurs.

When the completion occurs you have to do the following....

1. Call `setsockopt()` with `SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT` on the accepted socket using the listening socket as the data...
2. Deblock your addresses using `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()`.
3. Process any data (if you allocated enough space in the buffer for data).

Note that by design `AcceptEx()` can be used to accept a new connection and return the initial data from that connection in one operation (this leads to slightly better performance in situations where you know you will always want some data before you can start doing things but is horribly complex to manage if you want to defend aginst the denial of service attack that can be launched simply by connecting and NOT sending data - I wrote about this [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html)).

If you do not want `AcceptEx()` to wait for data to arrive then simply provide a data buffer that is ONLY big enough for the addresses to be returned and pass 0 as the 'buffer size'. This will cause the `AcceptEx()` to operate like an overlaped `accept()` and return as soon as the connection is established.

Note that Martin James' initial comment to your question is in fact the answer you're looking for. Don't pass `outBufLen - ((sizeof (sockaddr_in) + 16) * 2)`, pass `0`.

Comment: Well done, +1 for going beyond the question and explaining some of the other problems with the OP C-style code, (ugh!).

Comment: I actually think that it's quite likely that the fact that overlapped and data buffer are out of scope when the accept completion occurs is probably the reason why he's not getting any completions. I expect there could be an access violation happening and the completion is just being thrown away.

Comment: OP: 'I do however get a completion when the client sends data'

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the input! One question though, should i call WSARecv after the completion or after AcceptEx. Currently I'm doing it after and I get the error 10057 which seems correct because a connection hasn't been established. Am I seeing this right?

Comment: Call WSARecv after the acceptEx completes AND you have updated the accept context of the accepted socket with a call to setsockopt().

Comment: So first Call setsockopt() with SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT then WSARecv?

Comment: Yes, you need to update the accepted socket or 'strange things' may happen it's not well documented but here's details of the failures I found when failing to do this after a ConnectEx() call (http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/05/winsock-connectex-shutdown-so-update-connect-context-and-wsanotconn.html) Once you've done that then start issuing your reads and writes as normal.

Comment: I'm running the example from MSDN and I get error 10057 after setsockopt() with SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT, what could be wrong?

Comment: Which example; please provide a link. What could be wrong? You have a bug in your changes? All very difficult to debug with no sight of any of the code involved...

Comment: sorry, here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524(v=vs.85).aspx Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: I think the docs are unclear. You need to call setsockopt() once the accept that you initiate with the call to AcceptEx() completes and the completion comes out of the IOCP (which isn't shown in the example code at that link).

Comment: Len -- this is an EXCELLENT answer. I'm sorry I can only up-vote this once.

Comment: @RobertH another problem with that example is that it doesn't set `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, because it is using `socket` and not `WSASocket`...

Comment: Janus, actually... The current MSDN documentation for the socket() call states that "The socket that is created will have the overlapped attribute as a default." so that aspect of the code, at least, is OK...